# What is the time and space complexity of the reversing operation some_list[::-1] in CPython?

Tags: python, time-complexity, cpython, space-complexity

Simple example of code to present the case:

```py
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [ do_sth(x) for x in a[::-1] ]
```

1) What are the time and space complexity of CPython operation for [::-1] in general?

2) In the above example of code is CPython creating some temporary value for a[::-1] until the loop will finish or is recalculating the value of the reversed list before/in every single step of the iteration?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the time complexity and space complexity of array\[::-1\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330006/what-is-the-time-complexity-and-space-complexity-of-array-1)

Comment: _"in place algorithm should be O(1)"_... Are you sure that it _is_ in place? Wouldn't that imply that the original un-reversed list would no longer be accessible? I'm pretty sure you can still interact with the original `a`.

Comment: @Kevin you are right, silly mistake, this need to take at least O(n) space. So the question is how long the temporary value is kept by CPython? Until the loop will finish looping or is destroyed and recreated every step?

Comment: It will be created once and stored until the list comprehension finishes. (This slice *generates* the loop, so you couldn't really calculate when the loop finishes if it wasn't external to the loop)

Comment: I will edit the question not to propagate the mistake, the in-place function is some_list.reverse().

Answer (score 1):

Using the normal `a_list[start:stop:step]` slicing interface **generates a new list** and therefor costs O(n) memory in the slice size.

`itertools.islice(a_list, start, stop, step)` iterates over a list using an iterator and avoids memory usage. However, it doesn't support negative indices. The external package `more_itertools` has the function `islice_extended` that does support negative values.

Comment: Or just use `reversed`.

Comment: Actually, `islice` doesn't allow negative `step`.

Comment: Yeah, a pity, though understandable (they want to support general case iterators). Thanks! Will update the answer.